# How can I fix the null of Context.QueryString in the OnDisconnected in SignalR (Asp.net Core)?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core, signalr-hub

I have used the SignalR with Asp.Net Core.

I have tried get the `QueryString` in the method called `OnDisconnected` but I only get the `null` exception.

How can I fix this exception?

I've tried following code:

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            const string tokenKey = "token";
            var token = Context.QueryString[tokenKey].ToString(); <- NULL

            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.INameValueCollection` (which the `Context.QueryString` is) will return null if there is no query string parameter with your `tokenKey` in the url. Assuming this is the case, the `NullReferenceException` happens to be thrown when you try to call `.ToString()` on the null reference.

Why in the first place are you calling `.ToString()` on something that already is a string? It'll return you the very same string you're calling it on. Just remove the `.ToString()`.